# How to Make the Limit null for Google Endpoint API

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

```
public CollectionResponse<Eateries> list(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
    Query<Eateries> query = ofy().load().type(Eateries.class).limit(limit);
```

The above is a snippet of code from the endpoint api to get a list.

I am attempting to set the limit to null so that all the entries on the DataStore server will be retrieved by using the below:

```
        List<Eateries> eateries = myApiService.list().set("limit", null).execute().getItems();
```

However it sill keeps limiting it to the value of whatever DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT is set to.

1. How can I set the limit to null so I can get all the entries in one go?
2. Could someone explain to me what the below line is doing:

   ```
       limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
   ```

Comment: I have just ended up creating my own APIMethod as editing this automatically generated one was taking too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do what you want:

```
public CollectionResponse<Eateries> list(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    Query<Eateries> query = ofy().load().type(Eateries.class);
    if (limit != null) {
        query.limit(limit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
```

It turns out this line is setting limit to the value of DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT if limit is null.

I tried setting DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT to 0 so that limit would then be 0 which effectively means no limit when used in:

```
ofy().load().type(Eateries.class).limit(limit);
```

However it was still coming back with an error saying something about chunk size has to be more than 0.

So I've more or less created my own ApiMethod which completely overlooks having a limit set completely.